# Getting unlisted videos in Youtube XML

Tags: xml, youtube

I'm having a problem. I want to list videos on a website, so I used the XMLs from my account to show them in a way that I control with HTML and PhP. Everything works fine but I realized that unlisted videos are not shown anywhere on my page.

Digging the problem, I've seen that they are just not in the XML that I take from http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/fredy31/uploads

Is there another XML file that I can call that would include those unlisted videos?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting unlisted videos is impossible.

That's why they are unlisted: So they cant be queried.